# How to create shaded divs like this with CSS

Tags: html, css

I need to create shaded divs like those shown in the image below, using only CSS.  Any idea about how to create them using less coding?

Thank you!

[image: Shaded divs]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a method using CSS's box-shadow, which is compatible in Firefox 3.5+, Safari 3+, Chrome, Opera 10.5+ and IE9+.

http://jsbin.com/usabe4

Multiple `box-shadow`s are being used to get closer to the desired effect than a single `box-shadow` is capable of:

```
#box1 {
    background: yellow;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 0 orange, 2px 2px 0 orange, 3px 3px 0 orange;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 0 orange, 2px 2px 0 orange, 3px 3px 0 orange;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 0 orange, 2px 2px 0 orange, 3px 3px 0 orange;
}
```

Comment: I wish I'd thought of that. I added a little of your code to your answer, I hope you don't mind.

Comment: thanks for the fast response but one thing more. If you see more precisely you could see that there are connections between a div and let's say its shadow. You solution is close to it very much, except the connections. Do you know how to connect a shadow with its div?

Comment: @Bakhtiyor I'm confused as to what you mean by "connections". Do you mean the black border around the edges of the box and its shadow?

Comment: If you do mean that, then it's achievable with the use of pseudo elements. Amazingly this method has virtually the same support as the previous box-shadow method, with the exception of the requirement for Opera 10.6+. http://jsbin.com/usabe4/2

Answer (score 3):

Did you try using box shadow in css 3:

```
box-shadow:5px 5px 0 #CCCCCC
```

For more details check:
http://css-class.com/test/css/shadows/box-shadow-blur-offset-light.htm

Comment: Welcome to SO! I've edited your answer for spelling + formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Put two `div`'s on top of each other (use `z-index`) and move the lower one two pixels down/right.

Answer (score 1):

Is a CSS3 [`box-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/box-shadow) close enough?

http://jsfiddle.net/4kS4F/

```
.box {
    width: 120px;
    height: 60px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background: yellow;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 0px #777;
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 0px #777;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 0px #777;
}
```

It's supported in many browsers: http://caniuse.com/#search=box-shadow

The notable exceptions are IE 7 and 8. If you need it to work there, you could use [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/) to provide the `box-shadow`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need only a white background (or any fixed background color) you can make the box an image with the colored part being transparent and the edges being your background color. Then you set that as the background image, while the background color can control the face color of the box.